# How to resolve MiniZinc error: "model inconsistency detected before search"?

Tags: compiler-errors, minizinc

MiniZinc IDE-xossPB reports:"warning: model inconsistency detected before search". 
What does it mean? How does one go about resolving such an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that the program that translates the MiniZinc file (.mzn) to FlatZinc file (.fzn) detects that the model is unsolvable.

A tip is to either loosen some of the domains or comment out some of the constraints and see if the error is gone. E.g. a constraint such as "constraint 1=2;" with give such an error, though it's almost never as easy as that.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep plugging away.